How to make a non button element clickable using JavaScript
I am trying to make the cells on a 5x5 grid change to a random color when clicked on.
I am having problems getting them to change when clicked.
I am unsure of how to make a non button clickable and unsure about how to target multiple id's in one statement vs doing it 25 times.
I tried with just the first square to test it out and could link it correctly. I tried to get element by the first id and add event listener with click and change color function.
I am almost positive that is my problem.
When I do this my entire grid disappears.


//linking elements to the script
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
document.getElementById('sqr0').addEventListener('click', change_color);

//function to create the grid cells
function create_grid(rows, cols){
    const grid_container = document.getElementsByClassName('grid_container')[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            const square = document.createElement('div');
            square.classList.add('square');
            grid_container.appendChild(square);
        }
    }
}    
create_grid(5,5);

//function to assign unique id's to each square
function id(){
    //targeting the grid div element, then the squares
    const grid_div = document.querySelector('.grid_container');
    const grid_cell = grid_div.querySelectorAll('.square'); 
    //loop to create a unique id on each square
    for (let i = 0; i < grid_cell.length; i++)
        grid_cell[i].id = "sqr" + i;
}
id();

//function to reset 
//just refreshing the entire page
function reset() {
    location.reload();
}

//function to generate a random color
//used https://css-tricks.com/ to help with generating random color
function get_random_color(){
    let random_color = math.floor(math.random()*16777215).tostring(16);
    return;
}

//function to change the background to a random color
function change_color(){
    element.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>YOUR title here</title>
<meta name="description" content="brief description of YOUR page here">
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords related to YOUR page here">
<meta name="author" content= "YOUR name here">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="grid.js" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid_container"></div>
    <div>
        <button id="reset">Reset Grid</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
   




You try to assign an event listener to an element that doesn’t yet have an id (line 2).  Try moving line 2 after where you call the id function (id())

Check this out for adding a click event for div
 function create_grid(rows, cols) {
  const grid_container = document.getElementsByClassName('grid_container')[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.classList.add('square');
      grid_container.appendChild(square);
      square.addEventListener('click', change_color); // Add event listener here
    }
  }
}
function get_random_color() {
  const random_color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  return `#${random_color.padStart(6, '0')}`; // Ensures color has 6 characters
}

// Function to change the background to a random color
function change_color(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
}

The number 16777215 is used here because it represents the maximum value for a 24-bit color in hexadecimal format, which is the standard for RGB colors in CSS.

My squares still aren't changing. My grid no longer disappears when I try to link the the change color function, so I know I am closer to where I need to be. I still don't get why the background won't change on click.

I figured out some more of my problems after that last comment. Some rookie mistakes, a couple of lower case Math's etc. Thanks for the help guys
